# Что быстрее: EntityGraph или работа в транзакции?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, spring-jpa, spring-data-jpa

Приложение на `Spring Data`, `JPA`, `Hibernate`. В приложении есть много сущностей с большой вложенностью. Например:

```
// первая сущность
@Entity
public class First {
    
    @OneToMany
    private Set<Second> seconds;
}

// вторая сущность
@Entity
public class Second {

    @ManyToOne
    private First first;

    @OneToOne
    private Third third;
}

// третья сущность
@Entity
public class Third {
    
    @OneToOne
    private Second second;
}
```

Теперь для First мне надо сделать DTO, в котором будут участвовать все вложенные классы. Я не хочу использовать `FetchType.EAGER`. Я могу использовать `@EntityGraph`, чтобы загрузить весь граф за раз, а могу вытаскивать нужные мне части графа в методе отмеченном `@Transactional`.

Допустим, в каждом случае я буду вытаскивать один и тот же граф. Какой способ будет более производительным?

Comment: Какой диалект бд?

Comment: @RomanC бд postgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

Оба варианта одинаковы по производительности: все данные загрузятся за 1 запрос.

При этом надо понимать, что если сделать `FetchType.EAGER`, то независимо от того, из какой части системы (приложения) выполняется запрос данных, всегда будет подгружаться один и тот же полный набор данных, а это не всегда требуется, и может приводить к потере производительности в других частях системы.

Собственно, из-за необходимости в разных частях системы делать запрос одной и той же сущности с одновременной загрузкой разных дочерних сущностей с разной глубиной вложенности и появились `@EntityGraph`.

Используйте `@EntityGraph` внутри транзакционного метода.

Comment: Я так понимаю, вы сравниваете использования графа и использование FetchType.EAGER? Просто я сравниваю граф и работу в транзакции. Мне кажется, в транзакции будет не один запрос, а несколько.

Comment: `FetchType.EAGER` не значит, что загрузка будет в один запрос. `FetchType.EAGER` означает, что при получении объекта, ассоциация должна быть загружена. Как именно - это другой вопрос, может быть и отдельным(и) запросом(ами). За это отвечает FetchMode.